# Refreshing the prompts for Oracle BI Reports.

Tags: oracle-bi

There are a few prompts on the report of which some are prompts are dependent on other prompts. The user unchecked values on the prompts and is being considered as “’All” and null value is passed to the report.

When the value in the prompt is unchecked, the prompt(s) display a blank and the value being passed to the back-end is NULL and is perfectly fine. The problem is when the user unchecked the values of the prompt on which the other prompt is dependent, both/all the prompts gets refreshed to ALL.

Comment: Are you talking about BI Publisher "reports" or OBI "analyses". I know people use these terms like they meant the same thing but they are totally different technologies and akin to calling a cow a sardine just because both are biologically alive.

Comment: I am  talking about BI Publisher "reports"

Comment: Next time please be specific about this and include version numbers as well. Unprecise questions = no responses or unfitting responses